# Is there a way to make the "findpeaks" function run faster on a large dataset?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset called "endata" - 5.9 million data points. This represents data over a 90 day period. The dataset is a single vector. The first five data points look something like this:

```
0.0171365458527622 0.0174577280551263 0.0177808003184100 0.0181056613918160 0.0184322165779018 0.0187603772480992
```

I would like to use the "findpeaks" function from the pracma package. This is a line of code that I would like to use:

```r
y <- data.frame(findpeaks(-endata,minpeakdistance=10, nups=1, ndowns=1, npeaks=Inf, minpeakheight = -0.5, sortstr=FALSE))
```

The function takes a long time (hours) to run. Is there any way to make the function run faster? I have already tried splitting the dataset by individual days but this makes the output difficult to manage.

Comment: Split the dataset into individual days, run in parallel, and manage the output. If you have 8 cores, running in parallel could potentially get you an almost 8x speedup.

Comment: If you could adapt your data to `findPeaks()` from `monitoR`, it has a parallel option built in as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The negative `minpeakheight` is used to find the trough of the data points

Comment: The other option would be to try to optimize `findPeaks`. You would want to begin by profiling the code to see where the slow parts are. I see [for example, that they use `gsub`](https://github.com/cran/pracma/blob/master/R/findpeaks.R). Switching to `stringi` functions would probably be faster, but there's no way to know if it will be 5% faster or .0005% faster unless you profile first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parallel computing in R to speed this up. Vary `cores=` to suit your machine.

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores = 5)

y <- data.frame(findpeaks(-endata,minpeakdistance=10, nups=1, ndowns=1, 
                npeaks=Inf, minpeakheight = -0.5, sortstr=FALSE))

registerDoSeq()
```

Comment: DoMC is very useful but I find the need to turn it off after, `registerDoSEQ()` will bring you back to sequential operation. My Linux box gets squirrely when I keep DoMC running.

Comment: @oaxacamatt Oh, definitely. I shouldn't have assumed the OP would know to do that. Thanks. I'll edit the solution.